# get an html element top and left properties data

Tags: c#, html, mshtml

i'm using the mshtml dll to develop a helper to ie,
i'm trying to get the position of an htmll element,
i have an object with type of HTMLAnchorElementClass
when i'm trying to get his style.posTop value i get a null ref exception

is there a better way to do it?

maybe other cast?

please help

Comment: How are you retrieving the element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example I found (the way you're obtaining a reference to your element object is probably different, but take a look at this anyway:

```
Element = <however your get your element>;

//--- Determine real element size and position relative to the main page.
int ElementLeft = Element.offsetLeft;
int ElementTop = Element.offsetTop;
mshtml.IHTMLElement TmpElem = Element.offsetParent;
while (TmpElem != null)
{
     ElementLeft = ElementLeft + TmpElem.offsetLeft;
     ElementTop = ElementTop + TmpElem.offsetTop;
     TmpElem = TmpElem.offsetParent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
element.offsetTop
element.offsetLeft
```

Answer (score 0):

This method couldn't work with this link http://s1.webstarts.com/VacationHome/rates.html.
With the item 


High season:

The absolute top is 526
and with the item :
$160 / nt or £95 / nt 


The absolute top is 545. 
The distance btw them is too large